# How do iostream references evaluate to true/false

Tags: c++, stl

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num;
    stringstream ss("1");
    if (ss >> num) cout << "It was true\n";
    return 0;
}
```

How is "ss >> num" able to evaluate to a boolean value?  Is there some operator that's been overloaded in stringstream?  The STL says that the >> operator returns a reference to a stream.

Answer (score 4):

Yes- the iostreams have an `operator void*` in C++03 and an explicit conversion to `bool` in C++11.